# How to add highchart in my view.py?

Tags: python, django, pandas, highcharts

Anyone have idea on how to add high chart in view.py? which mean my data are filter base on the python code and from the dataframe convert to highchart.

Answer (score 2):

Install django-highcharts using pip (we do recommend to do it in a virtualenv).

```
git clone https://github.com/novapost/django-highcharts.git
cd django-highcharts
pip install -e ./
```

To integrate it into a Django project, simply add it to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# some interesting stuff...
'highcharts',
# some other stuff...
]
```

Don’t forget to set your STATIC_ROOT path and to run the following command to update the static files:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**view**

```
from highcharts.views import HighChartsBarView

class BarView(HighChartsBarView):
    categories = ['Orange', 'Bananas', 'Apples']

    @property
    def series(self):
        result = []
        for name in ('Joe', 'Jack', 'William', 'Averell'):
            data = []
            for x in range(len(self.categories)):
                data.append(random.randint(0, 10))
            result.append({'name': name, "data": data})
        return result
```

**template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("{% url 'bar' %}", function(data) {
            $('#container').highcharts(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Please note that the highcharts.js file should be called after the JQuery library.*

Look into [Documentation PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-highcharts/latest/django-highcharts.pdf) for details.

**EDIT 1**

Install the package using pip

```
pip install pandas-highcharts
```

Import it in your views

```
import pandas_highcharts
df = ... # create your dataframe here
chart = pandas_highcharts.serialize(df, render_to='my-chart', output_type='json')
```

n your templates

```
<div id="my-chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Highcharts.Chart({{chart|safe}});
</script>
```

Comment: cannot insert in view.py? ,mean python fall? because i need pull data from the filter datafram that all in python file

Comment: **git clone https://github.com/novapost/django-highcharts.git
cd django-highcharts**
my pip not running of this statement

Comment: did you clone successfully ?

Comment: Not able, this error i get **'module' object has no attribute 'serialize'**, anyone have any suggestion that i can refer based on basic, because I'm new to python, django and highchart